# Error message meaning after rendering 3d cube with bevy?

Tags: performance, rust, gpu, bevy

Hello I tried bevy today and I rendered a simple scene:
a little plane with a cube on it, with basic light and shadow.
But then I looked into the terminal and saw following errors:

```
2023-08-24T13:11:17.972906Z ERROR wgpu_hal::vulkan::instance: GENERAL [../src/amd/vulkan/radv_physical_device.c:2160 (0x0)]
    Device '/dev/dri/renderD128' is not using the AMDGPU kernel driver: Invalid argument (VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER)    
2023-08-24T13:11:17.973038Z ERROR wgpu_hal::vulkan::instance:   objects: (type: INSTANCE, hndl: 0x55da9cf75960, name: ?)
```

Can someone please explain what these errors mean?

I googled it and it didnt help. I also searched the zypper repo for amdgpu software. Was already installed.